# Shrink MacOS guest (vmdk file)

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-image

Is there a simple way to maintain a MacOS VM? I setup a VM with growing disk, which had original just 8GB. How I have a 45GB monster drive with a low real usage. I had to install a 8GB ziped package which was extracted 16GB "small" and then I installed that package which caused even more disk usage. I deleted the temporally files, but the disk kept fat.

So far the story. I tried override the empty space by zeros, however Apple removed the options multiple times over the time. In the end I used dd to override, at least a bit of the disk (I got scared that my host hdd will be filled up and I broke up the operation when the image grow by 4 attentional GB).

Now I tried to shrink the disk, but surprise virtual box does not support shrinking for vmdk files.

I'm trying right now to convert the disk to the vdi format and retry the shrinking. Is there a better way to achive that then `dd`ing the virtual disk, convert the disk and shrink it then?

Small update: The conversion and shrinking had no effect (by side of doubled disk usage).

I'm just thinking about what I read today. Is it possible that the disk is encrypted? That would cause that the raw bytes on my real disk are not null and therefore the drive cannot be shrinked.

Comment: if you're not on Windows, then just mount the VDMK file on the desktop & check its encryption from there. I'm not certain whether you can decrypt from the Finder, but it would be worth a look. If you're on Win or nix, tough luck, you have no license & no access to the encryption algorithms ;)